# Trying to convert Facebook pixel to HTML

Tags: html, facebook

I'm not currently a developer but am trying to work with IT on our Facebook pixel. They said they can't put the pixel in because it strips out anything within the `<script>` tags. Any chance anyone knows how to convert the pixel to HTML? Can't figure it out on Facebook's Developer site.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: do you mean this? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/v2.7

Comment: _"because it strips out anything within the tags"_ - what is "it"? If you want to implement a tracking code, then you need to be able to insert at least HTML code in one form or another.

Comment: The note I have from IT is: The Facebook tracking code won’t work on our website because it will strip out anything within the <script> tags. When I get tracking pixels, I have them sent over in HTML.

Does anyone know if it is possible to convert the FB-generated tracking pixel into HTML? That's what I'm struggling to find.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to convert Javascript to HTML. These are 2 different things for different tasks. The HTML is the place where Javascript should be placed - directly or as external source to load.

Simplest thing I can think of is to place the JS in separate file and load it with script tag like so, there would be nothing to remove then:

```
<script src="fb-pixel.js">
```

And within that fb-pixel.js:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
// Insert Your Facebook Pixel ID below. 
fbq('init', '<FB_PIXEL_ID>');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Your website system removes scripts for good safety reasons probably, but there should be a one way or the other to do the task.